# Will learning WPF improve my skills in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, vb.net

I have worked in Windows Forms for years, and still do. I'm not acquainted at all with the ASP.NET technology and no other Web related technology.

I have worked with:

1. Oracle Form Builder;
2. Visual dBase 7.5;
3. Delphi 2.0, 3.0 and 7.0;
4. Sybase Power Builder 10.5;
5. Visual Basic 6;
6. Visual Basic 2003/2005/2008;
7. And ultimately, Visual C# 2005/2008.

I'm mostly a C# programmer with a growing experience in VB.NET for the current year.

**What would be the way to go to learn WPF the best possible way while taking into account my experience?**

**And I'd like to know, will learning WPF improve my skills in ASP.NET and the like?**

Comment: Working with WPF will help with learning Silverlight, which is one way of producing rich content for hosting on an ASP.NET site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Working in WPF will improve your skill in WPF (unless you consider the general gains you get when working in any .NET language...in which case working in anything .NET will improve your ASP.NET skills).

If you want to improve your ASP.NET skillset, work with ASP.NET.

Comment: +1 Lean and swift! Yet, I can hardly see, with my poor knowledge of XAML and ASP.NET, any difference between those two. XAML is some sort of tag programming where you have such `<instruction parameter=??>` stuff. I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: In ASP.NET, you're working with HTML markup (with ASP.NET tags mixed in). In WPF you're working with XAML (another UI markup language). While HTML and XAML may look similar, then share nothing except their XML roots which is why learning WPF isn't going to help with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 3):

WPF and ASP.NET are totally different platforms. WPF is mostly used in Windows based applications. ASP.NET is for the web applications. If you are interested in learining anything related to web I would suggest learning ASP.NET MVC.

Learning WPF will certainly help you in understaning Silverlight better as both these technologies are based on XAML and share lot of things in common. Silverlight is used in web applications as well but mostly for applications which are rich in meadia and graphics content. If you intend to work on that kind of applications you can learn WPF or Silverlight.

Comment: +1 Agreed that WPF is Windows based. Aside, it seems you can bring WPF to the Web through Silverlight, if I'm not misunderstanding both technologies. If I build a Windows application by putting each of my forms out of my project, and use a project only for my forms which references my main project, let's say my core project, considering that the forms are the GUI only, I would be able, I believe, to bring my "Windows Application" to the Web by writing only the GUI in ASP.NET and referencing my core project within it. Are my beliefs correct?

Comment: You are almost right. Even with WPF you can build applications which are hosted inside the browser. It is true that most of the concepts which are applicable in WPF are similar in Silverlight as well. But some of the controls are available only in WPF and not in Silverlight. A simple google search should reveal these differences. I would say in general the XAML markup is almost same. If you know one technology like WPF it is very easy to get going with Silverlight. The basic concepts related to controls, events, styles and databinding are same.

Comment: Also, 9 years later, I would add that Silverlight is deprecated, however it's worth noting that XAML is used with Xamarin, the .NET cross-platform mobile-app framework from Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

Working in WPF will only enahnce your WPF skills and still WPF is a desktop based technology, ASP.Net is web based technology , seeing your skills matrix and past experience , i would say to learn WPF although this is not a constraint after all you a are a programmer and learn any thing but WPF will give you definately a plus in your Technical Stack.

If you learn WPF , it will be also eaiser to learn Silverlight , which is a web technology similar to Adobe flash.

Comment: +1 For pointing me out to WPF and reassuring me with my past experience. As a matter of fact, I have no experience at all in Web based applications, except in HTML and a bit of Javascript (since about 15 years ago lol). Aside, shan't it be doable to build a Windows Application, separate the GUI from the core project, and then reference the core project within an ASP.NET GUI project to bring my application to the Web? I think this could work right, I don't know for sure. Nonetheless, ASP.NET is just a GUI programming language, right? What makes me fear are all these complementary tools.

Comment: (continue...) such as Ajax, and other stuf like that. We don't have that much of controls and complementary tools in Windows Forms and we're able to build solid applications as well. I understand the advantages of refreshing through an UpdatePanel in Ajax, though I have never worked with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to learn WPF is to find a project (open source or paid for) that requires its use. That's the best way to learn anything - find a use for it.

Comment: +1 Agreed with the fact that being in front of a WPF project, this will let me no other choice than to learn out of it. That is the way I have learned Power Builder and the others. Nevertheless, I can see no advantages of going WPF, and am wondering whether I should give it a try, in case I like it better than the traditional Windows Forms with which I use to work.