# What ASP.NET programming model to choose?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

**Summary**

I'm a seasoned programmer with years of experience in Windows Forms development using different programming languages as already stated in this question:

[Will learning WPF improve my skills in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337613/will-learning-wpf-improve-my-skills-in-asp-net)

ASP.NET or any Web based programming language doesn't feel natural for me to explore or to use. Although I am unfamiliar with Web based technologies, my curiosity about these grows and grows. In addition to it, I am aware of the market place Web based programming takes. I would like to expand my knowledge and experience to the Web, though would it be just to know what I'm talking about instead of speculating whatever.

My experience as an information and process systems developer allows me to understand the concepts and some of the basics. I am aware that Web based applications are stateless, for instance, and that I need to use session or viewstate variables to keep the information the user is working with alive, otherwise I would loose them.

I also understand the basics of Ajax based controls such as the UpdatePanel, which is to update or to refresh only a part of a UI page rather than reloading everything through the connection again.

I can get that CSS defines styles for your page's sections and that you may change radically your Website's aspect just by changing the CSS reference.

I am also aware of masterpages, which I don't really understand, in fact.

**Programming Model**

I just watched this video about choosing the right model for me/my application:
[`Choosing the Right Programming Model`](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/choosing-the-right-programming-model)

If looks like ASP.NET MVC, which I thought was the best approach, is more for the veteran Web developers, people who are comfortable with Web applications.

I have used a lot of DataBinding in Windows Forms, and WebForms seems to be more what I'm looking for into ASP.NET, until they say that MVC allows for Unit Testing, TDD and Agile methodologies, which I adhere to, as a certified Professional Scrum Master.

I'm a bit mixed up on what will be more natural for me speaking of programming model.

**Questions**

1. Taking into account my base of knowledge and my experience, what programming model do you think I'm going to be more comfortable with?
2. Will choosing one over the other allow me to get acquainted enough with ASP.NET to one day try the other model?
3. In the video about choosing the Programming Model both sat on ASP.NET, I heard about DataBinding while using Web Forms, but no mention of DataBinding in the MVC model. Is there any possible DataBinding in MVC?

**Finally**

I'm very confused about all of this ASP.NET stuff.

Comment: SCRUM doesn't have anything to do with TDD or Unit Testing.  WebForms can be just as scrummy as MVC.

Comment: @jfar: That, I know already and needed not to be mentioned. My point is only that Scrum claims good development practices such as TDD and the like, and since I was certified PSM I, this meant I hold such programming techniques close to my heart. That's all!

Comment: This note is to everyone who answered and commented.  This was a very refreshing experience to see a question like this NOT degernate into a holy war.  All of you put very well thought-out answers and comments, none of them falling back to the "this way is better" aregument.  Kudos to everyone!

Comment: That is indeed the kind of `professional` exchange that is making us all growing by enlarging our points of views while fully taking advantage of a whole community of professional. Thanks to everyone! I now just don't know what answer to accept since you bring all important concerns and good philosophy behind your answers. Thanks to all! And by the way, I have begun the MVC Music Store ASP.NET MVC tutorial to get acquainted with it, so that I know what I'm talking about. And since Webforms should be easier for me, than having a minimum of MVC experience might help get through it when needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is so subjective that it's likely to get closed and no matter what answer we give, it's likely to get downvotes as well as ups, BUT....

Given your familiarity with WinForms development I would say to go to WebForms if you want to get up and running as quickly as possible.  Even if you eventually switch to MVC, you'll be more comfortable with WebForms at first while you learn the ins and outs of web development, so it will be less of a shock to your system.

And just so I don't get pegged as being biased by the others who will view this, I realize that there are many advantages to MVC, but in my own humble opinion, I think it's silly to get into a "Which is better" discussion.  I'm giving this answer because he asked (paraphrasing) "which will be easier for me to grasp and get started with".

**Edit**
I guess I only addressed the first two questions above...

For the third, databinding in MVC is a bit different, but not all that much. The data access under the hood is the same, but you control the output a lot more strictly.

See this other post for a quick glimpse at a good answer explaining how to do a simple "binding".  The asker in this question was less familiar with MVC, and was asking how to do databinding on a drop-down list in MVC. The answer given was good, and pointed to a good article.

[ASP.Net MVC framework and databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281144/asp-net-mvc-framework-and-databinding)

Comment: +1 Thanks for your input! At least, although this might be a subjective question and is likely to be closed, I will have had the chance to hear from someone. That is all that I ask. =) It's hard to speak of something we don't know. In my opinion, SO and its community is here to help, and that is exactly what you just did. Thanks again.

Comment: +1 Additionally, even with WebForms, you do not need to compromise on TDD. You can always use patterns like MVP (as an example) which will ensure that testability of your application can be high

Comment: @InSane: Thanks for your comment. This helps me a lot, really. It is sad to see that not all SO users see the purpose of such question as this one and vote to close it. Yet, it enlights some questionning I have about Web applications. =)

Comment: @David: You're paraphrasing right, that is mostly what I asked about. It's a shame that some people can't stand such confusion from one who doesn't know, and fall into a "which-is-better" discussion, which wouldn'T definitely answer the question, in the end. You got me right. And everyone who answered here also did. I'm glad I could all have your inputs. Thanks! I gratefully appreciate.

Comment: I agree that if you're coming from WinForms, the WebForms will make a lot more sense than MVC, but in my experience MVP + WebForms will generate a much higher volume of code (& development time) than a similar MVC application, primarily because conventions in MVC require much less code to be explicit. My own team noticed about a 3x increase in development speed once we got comfortable with MVC and had built some additional UI conventions beyond the OOB html helpers/input builders.

Comment: @Ryan: My sincere thanks for sharing your professional experience. That is relevant and appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

just go with asp.net mvc.

it will actually improve the way you write windows apps.

its a mistake to try and find the closest similar paradigm to what you are used to.   Its almost better to have a completely different one as it will save getting confused by things that are similar but not quite the same.

basically webforms was microsofts attempt to make it easier to do web stuff coming from the windows world.   But its akin to coming from a sailing background and developing a "car" that you control as if it was sail boat.   You are simply better off learning how to drive a car,  drive when you have to drive, sail when you have to sail.

so you will have to put in the effort to understand web stuff.   Its not too hard, it can just take a bit of time.  But there is a massive resource of knowledge to draw on.

basically come to web development with your cup empty ready to learn :)

Comment: I'm voting this up even though it's the opposite of my answer because there is a very good point in here about having a completely different paradigm.. When I switched from VB6 and classic ASP (using vbscript) I switched to C# because I found that I kept trying to do things the old VB way.  Switching to C# forced me to look at things differently.  (And I like the Zen reference)

Comment: I agree with @Keith on this, although WebForms might be more *natural to you* initially with your Windows Forms background ASP.NET MVC is more natural to the web in general. In my opinion ASP.NET MVC is Microsoft great way of saying "oops, sorry, we tried to make the web state full and that was not quite right". If you want to learn web development embrace it fully (learn HTTP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, stateless, and so on) and you'll be better off in the long run...even if the initial shock is a bit to hard.

Comment: +1 I see what you mean, and I must admit that I like it. Just like to learn, let's say, the German language, just go in immersion to Germany and learn there, not just try to learn from some local buddies who has learned German from school benches, because they first of all speak the same mother-language as you do.

Comment: I agree. I'm actually a bit frightened about WebForms because when I use it I feel I'm being tricked into thinking I'm not developing for web, even though I am, and when i want to do something web-ish I have to "trick" WebForms to function in the way I want it to. That being said, I went from php to winforms to ASP.NET, so I already knew my way around the web. At first I was super excited as to how I could use data-bindings and stuff, but once I tried to do something that was easy in php because php is designed to work with stateless requests and the like, I ended up pulling my hair out.

Comment: @Will Marcouiller: That comment made me think of the quote "When in rome, do as the romans". Well, when working with web, work with how the web works, don't try to bend it into looking like something you already know.

Comment: @Alxandr: Agreed, that is the best way to learn about Romans. I didn't know how to formulate the my thoughts, but that is about what I wanted to say when I've written that thing about learning the German language. In fact, I'm now following a step-by-step tutorial about ASP.NET MVC which is the Mvc Music Store tutorial. I already learned a lot, but more still to come! =) Besides, I plan to program on SharePoint someday, but first I will learn ASP.NET the right way, then I'll go with SharePoint. Aside, SharePoint is in Web forms, which I think will be easier to master when I have learned MVC.

Answer (score 3):

I use WebForms and I came from VB6. It was weird at the start when I had to learn about the page cycle.

Comment: +1 Thanks for letting me know your coming and what you use. I'm mostly a framework and the like developer, not to say an analyst and an architect. I don'T stick to these titles really. I prefer to say that I have a good understanding and, first of all, I love to help others and teach them as often as I can. So, others' help is welcome when I need it. =)

Comment: Yeah, coming to ASP.NET from Winforms, I think that "getting" the stateless nature of web development and the separation between the client and the server is the biggest mental block I had, but after that, the page lifecycle seems to throw most .NET developers for a loop.  +1 for mentioning it.

Comment: Hi David, asp.net has done some great videos. Web Forms http://www.asp.net/web-forms and MVC http://www.asp.net/mvc. However the only way to actually get into is to have project. To learn MVC I actually done this website http://www.need4motors.com. I'm still thinking about a project to learn ASP.net 4.0.

Comment: I've noticed you knew about those videos. Ooops...sorry.